# Where can I find the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files in my dashboard?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hello ExpressionEngine community,

My available options in the bar along the top when I log in are:

- Content
- Members
- Site Control
- New Entry
- Edit Entry
- Home

My best guess was "Edit Entry", but I get a message saying "An Error was Encountered You are not authorized to access this page".  Do I need special access rights to find the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The HTML should be under **"Templates/Template Manager"** in a tab called **"Design"** which is normally next to **"Content"**. If you can't see that tab then yes, it most likely is your account doesn't have the permissions to access that section.

It's also worth noting that the HTML should be there but depending how the site was set up the CSS and JS might not be there and you might need FTP access to the server.